# Expand and collapse animation on horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-animation, horizontalscrollview

I am working on an application which has an option to select through a list of products. I am showing these images/products (ImageView) in a HorizontalScrollView. Everything is working fine except this last requirement that I have: I have show an animation -  when the view is in the centre or while scrolling the view reaches centre, it should expand and all other views in the scroll view should shrink. kinda like the dock in the MacBook-when you hover your mouse over it it expands.

After searching a lot this is what I have come up with but this code works if the views are visible. I want to make it work if the views are in the center.

code to expand and collapse the views:

```
private void horizontalScrollAnimation(ImageView imageView1, ImageView imageView2, ImageView imageView3) {

    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    horizontal_scroll_view.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
    if (imageView1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        expand(imageView1);
    } else {
        collapse(imageView1);
    }

    if (imageView1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        expand(imageView2);
    } else {
        collapse(imageView2);
    }

    if (imageView1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        expand(imageView3);
    } else {
        collapse(imageView3);
    }


}
```

expand and collapse code:

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

how do I find out if the views are in centre in HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: You should Paste your code here, so that other people could understand what you have done and what you may have missed.

Comment: @HoseinIT, I have edited my question

Comment: https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView check  out

Comment: @RohitSharma, let me check that out

Comment: you should do this with recyclerview it is very good in comparision as compared to doing it with horizontal scroll view

Comment: @RohitSharma, But there are only three elements in my view and Recyclerview for just three elements seems like an overkill

Comment: In case you have only three elements expand the one which is centre as you will be having three distinct views get the view in the centre and expand it

Comment: @RohitSharma, okay, finding out the middle element is quite easy but unfortunately my expand and collapse code doesn't seem to work. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ObjectAnimator objectanimator1, objectanimator2;

 objectanimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"scaleX",1.0f,1.2f);

 objectanimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"scaleY",1.0f,1.2f); 


 objectanimator1.setDuration(4000);
 objectanimator2.setDuration(4000);

 objectanimator1.start();
 objectanimator2.start();
```

Comment: let me try this, will tell you if I face any issues